# How do I call upon CSS and Javascript in an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new when it comes to CSS and JavaScript. I've found a neat countdown timer to add to my website, but I'm not exactly sure how to add it to where I want it to go.

You can view the timer here: https://jsfiddle.net/ft8zoghr/1/

CSS:

```
html,body{margin:0px;padding:0px}
#cdt a img{border:0}
#cdt .demo{position:absolute;z-index:999;right:0;top:0}
#cdt #ie-fix{display:none}
#cdt .digit{background-image:url(https://d3qhtuwg866bv9.cloudfront.net/oc-sprite?bg_color=00000000&amp;date_label=&amp;encoding=png&amp;font=Kelly+Slab&amp;font_push_down=0.01&amp;height=90&amp;overlay_size=700%2C180&amp;quality=0.95&amp;renderer=v1&amp;scale=1.124&amp;shadow=1&amp;shadow_blur=4&amp;shadow_color=ffffff77&amp;shadow_y=0&amp;style=TemplateDigits01&amp;text_align=center&amp;title=&amp;txt_color=ffffffFF&amp;unit_labels=DAYS%2CHOURS%2CMINUTES%2CSECONDS&amp;use_overlay=1&amp;width=393);background-repeat:no-repeat;width:34px}
#cdt .digit-0{background-position:-315px -450px}
#cdt .digit-1{background-position:0px -405px}
#cdt .digit-2{background-position:-315px -360px}
#cdt .digit-3{background-position:0px -315px}
#cdt .digit-4{background-position:-315px -270px}
#cdt .digit-5{background-position:0px -225px}
#cdt .digit-6{background-position:-315px -180px}
#cdt .digit-7{background-position:0px -135px}
#cdt .digit-8{background-position:-315px -90px}
#cdt .digit-9{background-position:0px -45px}
#cdt .digit-x{width:17px;background-position:-730px -64px}
#cdt.widget-wrapper{width:393px;height:90px;position:relative;margin:auto}
#cdt .content-wrapper{width:100%;height:100%;background-position:0 -40px}
#cdt .spr{background-image:url(https://d29am0ph5s0t8u.cloudfront.net/production/cdt/widgets/sprites/image/1405744/oc-sprite.png?version=57509bf5-6)}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)
{#cdt .spr{background-image:url(https://d29am0ph5s0t8u.cloudfront.net/production/cdt/widgets/sprites/retina_image/1405744/oc-sprite.png?version=57509bf5-6);background-size:899px 202px}}
#cdt .counter-wrapper{width:374px;height:45.0px;margin-left:19px}
#cdt .counter-wrapper .counter-item{height:48px;float:left}
#cdt .counter-wrapper .counter-group{height:67px;float:left;position:relative;overflow:hidden}
#cdt .counter-group .unit-label{position:absolute;height:25px;width:67px;left:0;top:46px}
#cdt .days .unit-label{background-position:-393px -128px}
#cdt .hours .unit-label{background-position:-461px -128px}
#cdt .minutes .unit-label{background-position:-528px -128px}
#cdt .seconds .unit-label{background-position:-596px -128px}
#cdt .header{height:19px;width:100%}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cdt" class='widget-wrapper'>
<div class='content-wrapper spr'>
        <div class='header'>
        </div>
        <div class='counter-wrapper'>

            <div class='days counter-group'>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='unit-label spr'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='counter-item'></div>
            <div class='hours counter-group'>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='unit-label spr'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='counter-item'></div>
            <div class='minutes counter-group'>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='unit-label spr'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='counter-item'></div>
            <div class='seconds counter-group'>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='unit-label spr'>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

`Too long to put here`

In my website files, I've created a `count.css` file and a `count.js` file with the appropriate coding. I just want to know where I have to place them in my website's `index.html` file for the counter to show up.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve], and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I guess some 1min research would have resolved this question but here you go:

Put this in your  - tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="count.css">
```

and this in just before your closing -Tag:

```
<script src="count.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place them in the footer. Scripts should be loaded last to function properly. Not alway the case but better safe then sorry.

```
<script src = "example.js"></script>
```

Comment: Place calls to script libraries in the head tag

Comment: Placing scripts in the body tends to be better especially when not using a check for page loads (ie `$(document).ready(function(){  });`)

Comment: @MichaelMK I consider the footer part of the body. I always include mine in it. Unless you mean in the body right after the relevant html. I find that clutters the html too much for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but you're going to want to place the html somewhere withen the `<body>` tags

Example

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <!--css and js stuff-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="count.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!--THE HTML GOES HERE-->
      <script src="count.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something along the lines of:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="count.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <script 
      src="./path_to/count.js">
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do add js after html tag closes, preferably just before body tag closes. Otherwise if HTML was not ready by the time script get executed, then you get errors. Place you css between head tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="count.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="cdt" class='widget-wrapper'>
<div class='content-wrapper spr'>
        <div class='header'>
        </div>
        <div class='counter-wrapper'>

            <div class='days counter-group'>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='unit-label spr'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='counter-item'></div>
            <div class='hours counter-group'>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='unit-label spr'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='counter-item'></div>
            <div class='minutes counter-group'>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='unit-label spr'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='counter-item'></div>
            <div class='seconds counter-group'>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='counter-item'></div>
                <div class='unit-label spr'>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="count.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```